# Variable length sequences with keras and masking layers

Tags: python, keras

I have a sequence to sequence model designed in keras to predict numerical data but my input sequences are of varying length.  The sequences are stored in a numpy array where not present values are NaNs

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [NaN, 1, 2, NaN]]
```

for example.  The NaNs are always on the ends if there are any, the numbers are always unbroken sequences in the data so for example the following sequence doesn't appear:

```
[NaN, 0, NaN, 3].
```

I would like to use a masking layer in my model so that these NaN values are ignored however at the moment what I have doesn't work as the loss I get is always a NaN output.

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, 1), name='encoder')
masker = Masking(mask_value=np.nan)
masker(encoder_inputs)
encoder = LSTM(units, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)

# Keep encoder states for decoder, discard outputs
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder taking the encoder_states to be the initial state vector of the decoder.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, 1), name='decoder')

# Full output sequences and internal states are returned.  Returned states are used in prediction / inference

decoder = LSTM(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)

# Gives continuous output at each time step
decoder_dense = Dense(1)
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# create model that takes encoder_input_data and decoder_input_data and creates decoder_target_data
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

I guess I haven't correctly added the Masking layer to the model but I am not sure how to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using np.nan as my mask value.  As under the hood the masking is performed by multiplying with a binary mask which caused NaNs to always persist.  As my data is real numbered and I can't be sure of the range it will take I set my mask_value to be sys.float_info.max.

Comment: So, to clarify - `np.nan` should not be used as a masking value in `keras`?

Comment: This is similar to this issue in GitHub (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2819), but there the problem is with np.inf and not np.nan 
 - which should not trigger the reasoning you suggested, as np.inf is equal to np.inf, which cannot be said of np.nan